# Mail problem with Hungarian characters

Tags: c#, email, sockets, encoding, multipart

I have a multipart mail which is processed using async read on sockets. The problem is that instead of hungarian diacritics is displayed something like =ED which is the code in hexa of character. I suppose that is some encoding pb. I've tried several encoding from iso-8859-2 to utf7.

This is a part from mail header:

X-MS-Has-Attach:
X-Auto-Response-Suppress: DR, OOF, AutoReply
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
x-scanned-by: MH-MailNode {mn03} on 
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
MIME-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-2"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using UTF-8/UTF-16? It definetly sounds like an encoding problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to first decode the quoted-printable encoding. This is because the mail standard used to allow only 7-bit emails (not sure if this changed 'recently'). Search for quoted-printable on google, basically it is '=' followed by 2 hexadecimal characters. When you decode it, you will end-up with iso-8859-2 encoded text, based on your email headers.

Comment: Thank you. I've found a class the makes deconding and work fine for me. Here is the link http://www.aspemporium.com/classes_src.aspx?cid=6.